# Residency checks for Interrail passes?

Tags: trains, residency, interrail, eurail

I have already bought an interrail promotional global pass and paid for it. However, afterall, I found that probably I should buy Eurail pass (I am living in Ireland as an exchange student from Hong Kong, but my course only last for 11 weeks here. Therefore, I did not apply any visa or residency of Ireland.)

Here are two questions:
 1. Is it possible to change my interrail promotional global pass to eurail global pass? (I can pay the difference)
 2. How strict are the residency checks for Interrail passes for non-EU citizens in these days? If I could not change my interrail pass, I would like to try to use my interrail pass to travel in Euro.

P.S. I know our passport will be checked in the train. But how about the proof of residence?

Comment: What specifically is your citizenship?

Comment: What do you mean by "use my interrail pass to travel in Euro"? You don't mean to travel in a kind of money, right? If you mean travel in Europe, isn't that what an Interrail pass is for in the first place?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Interrail requires you to be an European resident (where Europe includes countries like Russia, Iceland, etc). The similar Eurail is for non-residents.

Comment: @MJeffryes My citizenship is Hong Kong

Answer (score 4):

Documents are **not** normally checked on the trains - certainly not proof of residency.

However, to be safe, you can always [get 85-100% of the Interrail Price refunded](https://www.interrail.eu/en/interrail-passes/ordering-info/return-policy#exchange), and then buy an Eurail pass.

Comment: On the train you might expect to have *identity* documents checked, to confirm that you are the person named on the Interrail pass, but I agree that residency will not be checked on the train: there's no mention of a requirement to travel with residency documents in the [conditions of use](https://www.interrail.eu/sites/interrail.eu/files/documents/interrail_pass_cou_2018988.pdf).

Comment: @Pont Nope, never has anyone asked for my ID card (except on the Istanbul-Ankara high-speed train, where the staff didn't seem very used to Interrailers)

Comment: @Pont On the other hand, being a Swedish citizen, I had to go back home and fetch my Swiss residence permit in order for Switzerland to be put as the "country" on the pass, as only one trip to the border and one from the border is allowed in that country. Never bring the permit with me otherwise other than for extension, including for my Interrail trip